# Suffer from or suffer with?

Tags: prepositions

> Many who suffer with lasting illness from Covid-19 struggle with fatigue, breathlessness, body aches and cognitive problems which some describe as “brain fog”.

Here how to read the "with"?
"Suffer from a disease" is commonly seen for me. I can't tell the difference between "suffer with" and "suffer from".

I've also seen "suffer great pain and discomfort". Could you tell me its difference and "suffer with"?

Answer (score 2):

The use of *from* in this context implies a cause, while the use of *with* implies something happening jointly or alongside something else.

The distinction will be made clearer if I replace the noun with *my friend*:

- I suffer *from* my friend.
  This means that you are experiencing suffering, and your friend is the *cause* of your suffering. Perhaps they are being annoying for some reason.
- I suffer *with* my friend.
  This means that you and your friend are suffering together. You are suffering and they are suffering. The cause of the suffering is not stated—perhaps you are both suffering *from* food poisoning.

Returning to the original question, the same analysis can be be applied if we use *fatigue*, for example:

- I suffer *from* fatigue.
  This means that you are experiencing suffering, and that fatigue is the *cause* of your suffering.
- I suffer *with* fatigue.
  This means that you are suffering *and* that you are experiencing fatigue. The two are not necessarily related. You could be suffering *from* a headache, and experiencing fatigue *in addition* to that.

Note that the object used somewhat changes the meaning of the *with* version. Unlike when you suffer *with* your friend, it would make no sense to think that the fatigue you are experiencing is suffering a headache *with* you—fatigue can't get headaches. However, it is still something that is happening at the same time, and separate from what is causing the suffering.

---

Having said that, some people do say *suffering with a headache* to mean the same thing as *suffering from a headache*. The distinction I made is the distinction that *would* be made if you are looking for a difference in meaning between the two.