# meaning of suffer with

Tags: meaning

> My OB/GYN wanted to put me on artificial hormones and painkillers,
> which scared me at age twenty-one to twenty-two. I refused and just
> *suffered with it*.

Source: Your Body in Balance. Neal Barnard, MD

I read the great answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/258232/suffer-from-or-suffer-with) but I'm still unsure about this one. Does "suffer with" here means "put up with" and "tolerate", or is it the same as "suffer from"?

Comment: We don't know the medical condition she has. That is what she has to "suffer with".

Comment: Premenstrual syndrome (PMS) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this online dictionaries definition:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suffer

> 1: to endure death, pain, or distress

Since the idea of using medical treatment to ease her symptoms scared the writer, one can understand she simply decided to 'endure' the symptoms.